# How can I optimize and speed up a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-performance, optimization

Below query never completes and runs for over 14 hours:

```
SELECT 
U.Age, U.CreationDate, U.DisplayName, 
P.AcceptedAnswerId, P.ClosedDate, p .Title, P.ViewCount,
C.CreationDate,C.Score ,C.UserId
FROM dbo.Users As U
LEFT JOIN dbo.Posts As P on U.id = P.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Comments As C on U.id =C.id
WHERE
(
U.Location = 'India'
OR U.Location ='United Kingdom'
)
AND U.LastAccessDate>= '04/02/2018'
AND U.LastAccessDate< '06/02/2018'
AND P.LastActivityDate>= '04/02/2018'
AND P.LastActivityDate< '06/02/2018'
AND U.LastAccessDate>= '04/02/2018'
AND U.LastAccessDate< '06/02/2018'
AND U.Age>10
AND U.Age is NOT NULL
```

How can I improve and speed it up ?

Comment: If possible, maybe upload the execution plan? so we can see indexes or stats?
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/
I'd think it needs some index on U.LastAccessDate/P.LastActivityDate or U.Location (depends on the numbers)

Comment: We need to see the execution plan. Irrespective of what indexes you have or how big the tables are seems like something is catastrophically wrong with it if it takes 14 hours (or you are encountering blocking). Corresponding query on SEDE executes in < 1ms. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1241776?opt.withExecutionPlan=true#executionPlan

Comment: You say "somewhat similar to below" and then give us a query that doesn't represent the problem. What is the **actual query** (with tables anonymised if needed)

Comment: @Martim Smith: I understand. I am trying hard to gather that. If possible can you suggest a way to construct or replicate the issue. Let me see if I can get that info

Comment: Just take the original query that shows the problem and anonymise the table names. The query you posted even with no useful indexes has equi joins so can do it with one pass through of all three of the tables involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem I see is in your joins. You're joining the "id" of Users, to the "id" of Posts and Comments. This basically says, take every record in Users and join it to every record in Posts, then join it to every record in Comments.

Presuming that the UserID exists as a foreign key in Posts and Comments, the code below should work. If not, you'll need to determine the correct foreign keys for the `JOIN` statements.

```
SELECT 
    U.Age, 
    U.CreationDate, 
    U.DisplayName,
    P.AcceptedAnswerId, 
    P.ClosedDate, 
    P.Title, 
    P.ViewCount,
    C.CreationDate,
    C.Score,
    C.UserId
FROM 
    dbo.Users AS U
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Posts AS P 
        ON U.UserID = P.UserID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Comments AS C 
        ON U.UserID = C.UserID
WHERE
    U.Location IN ('India','United Kingdom')
    AND U.LastAccessDate>= '04/02/2018'
    AND U.LastAccessDate< '06/02/2018'
    AND P.LastActivityDate>= '04/02/2018'
    AND P.LastActivityDate< '06/02/2018'
    AND U.Age>10
```

I replaced the location `OR` statement with an `IN`.

I removed the duplicated `U.LastAccessDate` conditions.

I removed the unnecessary `U.Age IS NOT NULL` condition.

If this query still runs slowly. My next best guess would be a missing index on Users.LastAccessDate and/or Posts.LastActivityDate.

Answer (score 1):

Here what you need to do:

1) use #Temp table
2) break down query on parts, get data step by step
3) make sure columns which you use in the WHERE or join ON clause, are indexed

Temp Table - column data types below are just an example, use data types that exactly match column data types on your tables

```
create table #UserInfo (
    tID                     int primary key clustered,

    tAge                    tinyint,
    tCreationDate           datetime,
    tDisplayName            varchar(50),

    tAcceptedAnswerID       int,
    tClosedDate             datetime,
    tTitle                  varchar(50),
    tViewCount              int,

    tCreationDate           datetime,
    tScore                  int,
    tUserID                 int)
```

Get Users info - make sure `Location`, `Age`, `LastAccessDate`  columns are indexed on Users table

```
-- get users info
insert into #UserInfo (tID, tAge, tCreationDate, tDisplayDate)
select 
    U.ID,
    U.Age, 
    U.CreationDate, 
    U.DisplayName, 
from dbo.Users As U
where   (U.Location = 'India' OR U.Location ='United Kingdom' )
        and U.Age > 10
        and U.Age is NOT NULL
        and U.LastAccessDate >= '04/02/2018'
        and U.LastAccessDate 

-- Get Posts Info - make sure ID, LastActivityDate columns on Posts table are indexed

-- get posts info
update #UserInfo
    set tAcceptedAnswerID = P.AcceptedAnswerID,
        tClosedDate = P.ClosedDate,
        tTitle = P.Title,
        tViewCount = P.ViewCount
from #UserInfo
    join dbo.Posts As P on 
        tID = p.id
        and P.LastActivityDate>= '04/02/2018'
        and P.LastActivityDate< '06/02/2018'

-- Get Comments info - make sure ID column on Comments table is indexed

-- get comments info
update #UserInfo
    set tCreationDate = C.CreationDate,
    tScore = C.Score,
    tUserID = C.UserId
from #UserInfo
    join dbo.Comments As C on 
    U.id =C.id

-- show data
select
    tAge                    [Age],
    tCreationDate           [CreationDate],
    tDisplayName            [DisplayName],

tAcceptedAnswerID       [AcceptedAnswerID],
tClosedDate             [ClosedDate],
tTitle                  [Title],
tViewCount              [ViewCount],

tCreationDate           [CreationDate],
tScore                  [Score],
tUserID                 [UserID]
```

from #UserInfo